# Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'. in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

learning angular and typescript for the first time and cannot understand why this is not valid!

http.service.ts

```
export class HttpService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBeer() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries')
  }
}
```

that api returns an object

```
the component its being used in: 


export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  brews: Object;

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.getBeer().subscribe(data => {
      this.brews = data
      console.log(this.brews);
    }
  )
  }

}
```

im getting an error in the line

```
brews: Object;
```

which says:

error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

i've tried:

```
brews: any;
```

and

```
brews: Object[] = [];
```

but nothing seems to work.

can someone explain where I am going wrong?

that api returns an object, so why cant I  do

```
brews: Object;
```

the template its being used for:

```
<h1>Breweries</h1>

<ul *ngIf="brews">
  <li *ngFor="let brew of brews">
    <p class="name">{{ brew.name }}</p>
    <p class="country">{{ brew.country }}</p>
    <a class="site" href="{{ brew.website_url }}">site</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the api response look lie? Seems that is an object type and hence the error. Post brew response.

Answer (score 2):

It is good idea create a custom type based on your `data`. But if you insist on using anonymous type you may need to use `any[]` type to solve the problem:

```
brews: any[];
```

And you can use generic methods in http client like `get<your_type[]>`:

```
this._http.get<any[]>('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries').subscribe(data => {
      this.brews = data 
      console.log(this.brews);
    })
```

OR something like this:

```
this._http.get('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries').subscribe(data => {
          this.brews = data as any[]
          console.log(this.brews);
    })
```

Here is working sample: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-fkg4i9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

it's a bad idea to name your service in the restricted name space. httpservice is not a good name to use and could lead to some weird problem later.

you should use a behavior subject which allows you to share the object as an observable from all components.

**service**

```
export class BeerService {
    private beer = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
        public beer$ = this.beer.asObservable();
      
        getBeer(){
          this.http.get('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries').pipe(map((res) => (res = res))).subscribe((sub) => {
            sub = sub;
            // set beer object next
            this.beer.next(sub)
            // , take(2)
             })
        }
```

on your **component**

```
  constructor(beer:BeerService) {}
  ngOnInit(){
       this.beer.beer$.subscribe((beer)=>{ 
      this.beer = beer})
  }
```

you can read about behavior subjects here.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject